What's the difference: 「ワンさんがはたらいているびょういんはこうべ［に・が］あります」

ワンさん が はたらいて いる びょういん は こうべ "が" あります。

ワンさん が はたらいて いる びょういん は こうべ "に" あります。


What is difference between those two sentences?

The first one says, "The hospital where Wan-san works has a Kobe".

In these sentences, the main verb is あります; then ワンさん が はたらいて いる びょういん is a topic marked with は. Finally, こうべ is either a grammatical subject marked with が, or a location marked with に.
This verb ある (inflected here as あります for politeness) is, for all intents and purposes, equivalent to English "to exist". However, it has some slightly different idiomatic usages.
In Japanese, the subject of a verb exists whether or not it's mentioned; there's no need to fill that place explicitly with an equivalent of "it". So if we say that something exists こうべに, there is still something that exists, even if we didn't use が to say what exists.
When a topic is mentioned but a subject is not, one common inference is that the topic also serves as a subject: when we are talking about the hospital where Wan-san works, and say in this context that something "is in Kobe", it should be clear that we mean that the hospital is the thing which is there. This is what happens in the sentence with に.
In the sentence with が, we are still claiming to talk about the hospital, but we are saying that Kobe exists, and this is somehow relevant to the hospital. This will generally be interpreted, idiomatically, as saying that the hospital has Kobe - which of course is nonsense.
Japanese doesn't have a direct equivalent of the English "to have", nor of "to be". Both of these English verbs are quite broad, and capture meanings that are considered very distinct from each other in many other languages (including Japanese). The idiom XはYがある for "X has Y" (lit. "regarding X, there is a Y") might seem a little strange, but this is also seen in other languages. A rough equivalent also appeared in classical Latin (the original source of somewhere around half of English vocabulary).
If you learned 持つ for "to have", please note well that it only covers possession ("I have a dog") and not e.g. a component relationship ("I have a nose"). And even then it will more often be used specifically as "to hold/carry".
Similarly, ある is specifically "to exist" - but this is a somewhat unusual verb in English but an extremely common one in Japanese. Natural translations in English may happen to use "to be" or "to have" depending on the context, but that is because of English being imprecise, not because of Japanese being inconsistent.
